# C# get file paths of just files with no extensions

Tags: c#, path, getfiles

I am wanting to get a string array of paths of files that do not have extensions. They are binary files with no extensions if that helps.

For example, I am loading a group of file paths out of a folder `/test/`

I want just the path and filenames that do not have a extension (so no `.txt`, no `.csv`, no `.*`)

`/test/dontWant.txt`

`/test/dontWant.csv`

`/test/doWant`

if i do:

```
String[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(fDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I of course get everything in those directories.

if I then try:

```
String[] paths= Directory.GetFiles(fDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I will still get everything in that directory.

**Is there a way to just get the files of those that have no extension?**

---

using `"*."` did work, and I don't know why I didn't try that to start with.

I should have been using `EnumerateFiles` to start with.

Comment: try `String[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(fDir, "*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: @Grundy Nope. That'd be any file name ending with a dot. I don't know of any file like that!

Comment: @tnw, are you try it???

Comment: @yep, it works :-), because file without extension have name "name."

Comment: @Grundy Interesting, I honestly did not expect that to work. Just tried it myself and it does. Cool

Comment: @RKlenka, are you try this wildcard "*."?

Comment: A pattern of 'star dot' as above passed to Directory.GetFiles seems to match files without extensions but also files with no names and ONLY extensions. I am seeing this in .NET 3.5. Anybody else seeing behavior like this? Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: “using "*." did work” why not working for me?

Comment: EnumerateFiles is not good if you create directory during the process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will help:

```
var filesWithoutExtension = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\temp\").Where(filPath => String.IsNullOrEmpty(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filPath)));
foreach(string path in filesWithoutExtension)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

It will return all the files w/o extension only in specified dir. If you want to include all the sub-directories you'd have to use: `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\temp\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

**UPDATE**
As guys suggested, it's better to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` because it consumes less ram.

Comment: This code works like a boss. Just tested it in a console app.

Comment: EnumerateFiles is not good if you create directory during the process.

Answer (score 23):

You can try with this wildcard

```
String[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(fDir, "*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

also you can use this wildcard with `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(fDir, "*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Although accepted answer works nice, but I prefer this solution because it's more readable and also less code used in

Answer (score 9):

You will need to do a 2nd pass filter on it.

```
//If you are using .NET 3.5 you can still use GetFiles, EnumerateFiles will just use less ram.
String[] paths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .Where(file => Path.GetFileName(file) == Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
                          .ToArray();
```

So what this does is it passes your file path to [`GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if both of those return the same string it then includes the result in the array.

Comment: +1 for `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and using less ram.

Comment: EnumerateFiles is not good if you create directory during the process.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to aleksey.berezan's answer, you can do the following in .NET 4+. `EnumerateFiles` will return files as they are traversed in the directory tree.

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(s))))
{

}
```

Comment: EnumerateFiles is not good if you create directory during the process.